# Sending faxes from Asterisk (email to fax) --- is any feedback possible?

Tags: asterisk, queue, fax

I am about to make some email to fax gateway --- some python program will make [Asterisk](http://www.digium.com/en/products/asterisk) [call files](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Call+Files) and put them into some queue (files or db based).

Then another program should take "call tasks" from queue and "feed" them to asterisk (honoring some configured limit, because of `res_fax_digium` will drop over-limited tasks).

Next, let's suppose, everything is great and asterisk successfully sent some fax document. What could be a way to get the status of this operation?

If logfiles parsing is the best, I would, probably, assign some special `accountcode` (I can play with this field, probably) to drop CDRs into separate files, too.

Please, which other ways I should evaluate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I dropped this approach and will go another way --- AMI, Asterisk Management Interface API.

In a couple of words.

Having created dialplan like this one:

```
[01-sendfax]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp()
     same => n,SendFax(${faxfile},f)
```

I can originate calls with (using [pyst](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyst/)):

```
res = mgr.originate(
    'SIP/m2000/1234567',
    '1234567',
    context='01-sendfax',
    priority='1',
    caller_id='7654321',
    async=True,
    variables={
        'TRUNK': 'SIP/m2000',
        'faxfile': '/tmp/file.tiff',
    }
)
```

And having set `debug = on` in `manager.conf`, I can listen to needed events:

```
# will catch a status of `originate` call
# (this does not require `debug = on` in `manager.conf`):
mgr.register_event('OriginateResponse', handle_response)

# will catch `SendFax` application's result:
mgr.register_event('FaxStatus', handle_response)
```

So, `res_fax_digium` fires `FaxStatus` event after `SendFax` is complete.